# MVC - Role Based Authorization Based On Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

im trying to create mvc application with role based authorization. Currently i want 2 roles only, admin and user. I already make simple authorization work, but still without role. I already search so many reference in internet but still cant find one that works with me. Please help, thank you.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            string loginquery = "select UserId,Password,Roles from UserAcc where "
                                    + "userId = @p0 and Password = @p1";
             var a= db.User.SqlQuery(loginquery,model.userid, model.password).Count() ;
            if (a>0)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.userid, false);

                Session["userid"] = model.userid.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");

            }

            else { return RedirectToAction("Login"); }

        }

        else

        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "EmailId or Password Incorrect.");
        }
            return View(model);
    }
```

I want the program to set role authorization based on role field in database

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [UserId]
  ,[Password]
  ,[Roles] FROM [ESS].[dbo].[UserAcc]
```

And i want to filter my controller like this

```
namespace TEST2.Controllers{[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
```

Thankyou,

Comment: Are you using asp .net membership or identity?